# My confusion with Java Lambda expression

Tags: java

I know that Java's Lambda expression can replace a parameter whose type is an Interface (only contains one method), but why I can execute code like this:

```
String[] myArray = new String[3];
Arrays.sort(myArray, (a, b) -> {return b.compareTo(a);});
```

In this case, the lambda expression `(a, b) -> {return b.compareTo(a);}` replaces an object of `Comparator` interface, but `Comparator` interface has more than one method, why?

Comment: It's only one `abstract` method.

Comment: Why not use `Arrays.sort(myArray, Comparator.reverseOrder());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for `java.util.Comparator`:

> Functional Interface:
>
> This is a functional interface and can therefore
>   be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method
>   reference.

`java.util.Comparator` is annotated with [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) which is:

> used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a functional interface as defined by the Java Language Specification. Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.

Comment: I think the OP's question is equivalent to "how can this be a functional interface?"/

Comment: Yes, is it because compare is the only method in this interface which doesn't have a default implementation?

Comment: @Haobo_X Yes, that's correct. `compare()` is the only abstract method

Answer (score 4):

You can do this because `Comparator` [only declares one method](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Comparator.java/?v=source) for which there is no default implementation. (You may notice that it redeclares `equals` without an implementation, but this is only to document the effect of overriding it in a `Comparator`. A default implementation is inherited from `Object`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718112/tostring-equals-and-hashcode-in-an-interface).)

Answer (score 0):

The comparator interface contains only 1 method: compare(...)
Because of this it is a functional interface which can be used with lambdas.