# Why can an abstract class force a concrete method to be overridden?

Tags: java, object, overriding, abstract-class

I use a library where an abstract class overrides a concrete method inherited from `Object` with an abstract method:

```
public abstract class A {
    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

To extend this class, I have to implement the `equals` method:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj.getClass() == B.class;
    }
}
```

---

Why can an abstract method (`A::equals`) override a concrete method (`Object::equals`)? I don't see the goal of this.

Comment: It's the opposite here - the base class has an abstract method and a non-abstract derived class has a non-abstract method which overrides the base class method.

Comment: @sharptooth My question was not very clear. I am talking about `A::equals` overriding `Object::equals`

Comment: I guess you should word that explicitly in the question. Since you only presented two of your classes I was sure the question was about them only.

Comment: `A` is not overriding `B`'s `equals()`, it's `B` overriding `A`, and is one of the most common thing to do when designing classes, because it forces you to do the implementation in `B` of `equals()`, it's like an `interface`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this specific example it makes perfect sense. If sub-classes of A are meant to be used in Collections, where `equals` is widely used to locate objects, making `A`'s `equals` method abstract forces you to give non-default implementation of `equals` in any sub-classes of `A` (instead of using the default implementation of the Object class which only compares instance references).

Of course, your suggested implementation of `equals` in B makes little sense. You should be comparing the properties of the 2 B instances to determine if they are equal.

This is a more suitable implementation :

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof B))
            return false;
        B other = (B) obj;
        return this.someProperty.equals(other.someProperty) && this.secondProperty.equals(other.secondProperty);
    }
}
```

In addition, remember to override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals` (since the contract of `equals` and `hashCode` requires that if `a.equals(b) == true` then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`).

Comment: If `B` has no other properties (and neither has `A`) which make instances different from each other, an implementation like in the question might be sensible. Though comparing with `this.getClass()` instance of `B.class` would be more correct when considering subclasses of `B`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe `B` is a Singleton

Answer (score 10):

Because in this case, you would want your objects to define their own `equals`, which supposedly will behave differently from the default implementation.

You should not look at this as *removing* functionality, but rather as enforcing that inheriting objects implement their own.

Comment: You are clear-sighted, i really saw this *as removing functionality*.

Comment: @gontard: In this case, you *want* implementing classes to stipulate their own behaviour. To do this, you would need to ensure that the default implementation is not accessible so that the desired behaviour is obtained.

Comment: Actually it [is still accessable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2692379/823393) but not at all easily.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I would hope that no one would do something like that by accident XD

Answer (score 6):

This would allow you to force a subclass to reimplement a method.  Whether this is a good idea or not is another matter.  You would only do this if you wanted to enforce a stronger contract than the original method provided.  You should then carefully document the new contract.

Answer (score 3):

It means you **must** implement your own `equals()` method

Answer (score 1):

Because all classes in Java inherently extend the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class. Class `A` will inherit the `Object#equals` method. Suppose you wanted to force a compile error when the equals method is not explicitly implemented like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612273/force-a-class-to-override-the-equals-method). Making the equals method abstract without an implementation block would enable you to do this.